# NSImageView setImage won't set image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, nsimageview

I am trying to set image for an NSImageView instance object in a Cocoa project. My code looks like this:

```
itemTableCellView * xx = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MainCell" owner:self];
    xx.label.stringValue = [tempCi simpleTxt];
    xx.img = [[NSImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(48, 48, 48, 48)]];
    NSImage * localimage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"menubar icon"];
    [xx.img setImage:localImage];
    return  xx;
```

The variable `img`is of type NSImageView. The variable `localImage` loads the correct image, I have checked it in the log. The variable `lable` is initialized correctly and gets the right value

I just keep on getting empty NSImageViews in my app.

Comment: Your `NSImageView` is initialized with no size (it's frame equals `NSZeroRect`), also you don't seems to add the image view to any subview.

Comment: I have changed the part where I was just initializing it. Now I am setting up a rectangle!

Comment: @Emmanuel Please write this your comment in an answer, I would then accept it! thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `NSImageView` is initialized with no size (it's frame equals `NSZeroRect`), also you don't add the image view to any subview.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
xx.img = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
```

Or, maybe, as `img` is property, you don't need to init it at all?
And just use

```
xx.img.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

Comment: I have tried:     `xx.img = [[NSImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(48, 48, 10, 10)];` but still doesn't work :(

Comment: If i dont initialize then `img` is nil

Comment: Are you adding it to any view?

Comment: @Marci-man As i'd say in my comment, you don't add your image view, to the views hierarchy.

Comment: well, `img` and `label` are a properties of variable `xx` and label is being shown just fine!

Comment: ..., despite the fact you didn't init it (label).

Comment: well, I init label in the init function of xx, I had also initialized the NSImageView there, but somehow it was returning to be nil, so i started initializing the it in the method itself!

Answer (score 1):

when you create your `NSimageView`,try doing an `initwithframe:`. This will set a size for the NSImageView. I believe that you might be drawing in a rect of size zero otherwise.

Comment: Nope, thats not the case, but thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 1):

Well, yet another quirk of Objective-C!

I found out that even when a `NSImageView` is a property of an `NSView`, it needs to be added to it through:

```
[xx addSubview:xx.img];
```

Well, played Cocoa, very well played!
cheers!

Comment: I can't accept the answer right now, but will do in a couple of days :)